# how to import packages automatically in python and ipython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython

There are a collection of packages(`numpy, pandas, scipy, matplotlinb, seaborn, etc...`) I need to use every time I open a python shell or notebook. It's annoying to import all of them each time, how to edit the profile of python/ipython to import them automatically?

Comment: Dirty hack to achieve this: create a module that does nothing but import your desired packages. Then you can import them all at once by executing `from mypackage import *`.